Passing in a file name to a constructor
I'm trying to build a constructor that takes a file name as an argument, opens and reads the file, but when I run my code I'm always getting Error:

file could not open

Here's a short version of my code (I'm very new to this, so please take that into account):
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);                      
    Matrix(string filename);                                
private:
    int nRows;                                     
    int nCols;   
    vector<float> data;                             
};

Matrix::Matrix(string filename) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    if (!file) 
        throw runtime_error("Error: Could not open file.");
    file >> nRows >> nCols; 
    data.resize(nRows * nCols);
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; ++i) 
        file >> data[i]; 
    if (!file) 
        throw runtime_error("Error: File format incorrect.");
}

int main() {

  Matrix m2(string("m2.txt"));
}


The most likely problem is there is no m2.txt in the current working directory. Depending on how you are running your code the current working directory may be the location of your executable or possibly the location of your project. Note that the current working directory is likely not your desktop. And on top of this if you are on MSWindows be careful that the OS file explorer hides extensions of known types by default. This hiding could have allowed you to create a file that is named m2.txt.txt and you didn't see the difference in the explorer.

The usual reason for not being able to open a file for reading is that the file does not exist, or more specifically, the file does exist but the program is looking for it in a different directory. There is nothing wrong with your code, if the file exists and is accessible then it should open.

In other words you have to ask yourself which directory did I put this file, why do I think that is the right directory, and what is the actual directory where my program is looking.

If you replace the whole program with #include <fstream> int main() { std::ifstream file("m2.txt"); return file.is_open(); } what exit code do you get when running it? You could also add if (!file) std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n'; after you've tried to open it to get a hint of why it wouldn't be opened.

What makes you think that this file would open?  Is there a file named m2.txt?  What directory is it in?  What is your current working directory?  std::ifstream::open will not search your entire computer for this file, only the current working directory.

Minor point: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing ifstream file; file.open(filename); to ifstream file(filename);.

Might try std::filesystem::exists and std::filesystem::current_path to check your current working directory.

One easy way to tell what your current working directory is, is to write a file, e,g, ofstream file("test.out"); file.close(); and then see what directory that file appears in. That is your current working directory.

Kamar: Here's a slight addition to your program that should show the problem more clearly: https://godbolt.org/z/Gb7PeYhWa

Design note : You don't want to pass a filename to a constructor, You want to pass a data structure to a constructor. (or at least a std::istream& not a filename).  By doing that you can also unit test your class from an std::isstringstream (or programmatically initalized datastructure)

You didn’t include  in your program. I don’t even understand how you managed to compile the program.
#include <fstream>

It seems to be that you put the file in a different directory from where the code is running or that the name of the file is not exactly "m2.txt". If you put the file in side of its own folder in the correct directory you would have to enter the name as "FolderName\\m2.txt" where "FolderName" is the name of the folder you put the file in.

Note that backslashes should be doubled since they're the escape character. Or use forward slash.
